# IE не отображает в Img скрин экрана

Tags: веб-программирование, html, internet-explorer, html5, img

Создаю скриншоты экрана с помощью утилиты Snipping Tool (стандартные ножницы в Windows), сохраняю их через эту программу в форматах png или jpg, во всех случаях расширения у файлов получаются написанными большими буквами, т.е. названия получаются примерно такими "imag1.PNG".

Когда подключаю такой файл через обычный тег img, т.е. `<img src="../content/imag1.PNG">`, к HTML странице, то в google chrome всё нормально отображается, а в Internet Explorer картинка не отображается. И даже когда в ручную меняю расширение "PNG" на "png", то всё равно не открываться. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема.

**Обновление**

1. Тестирую на локалке, т.е. просто создаю в виндовс файл с расширением html и открываю в браузере.
2. Попробовал без кавычек - не помогает.
3. Путь правильный, у меня просто документ в папке "page" лежит. К тому же в хроме он эту картинку открывает, да и если IE подсунуть png или jpg, созданную не в Snipping Tool, а, например, в фотошопе, то он нормально её открывает.
4. ОS Windows 8.1, IE версия 11.

Соответственно, без .. вообще не открывает в любом браузере, т.к. путь становится неправильным.

Открыл ещё в firefox, картинка открылась в нём.
В итоге какой-то жестокий парадокс получается: использую ОС от microsoft, создаю картинку, используя программу от майкрософт, редактирую код в блокноте от майкрософт, и в итоге единственный браузер, в котором эта картинка не загружается, - это браузере от майкрософт, а в остальных браузеров, которые у меня установлены, нормально всё отображается.
Архив с файлами - http://dfiles.ru/files/gonqels32

Answer (score 1):

Вы на локалке или на сервере?

Попробуйте без "..".

Т.е. просто `content/imag1.PNG`.

Вряд ли ваш HTML документ лежит на уровень выше, чем папка с картинками.

Comment: @Crus, обновил вопрос

Comment: А можете куда-то загрузить, чтобы можно было посмотреть?

Comment: Выложил архив с файлами  на файловое хранилище. http://dfiles.ru/files/gonqels32

Comment: У меня все нормально работает. Посмотрел код - тоже все отлично.

Попробуйте на другом компьютере открыть. Или попробуйте обновить без кэша в вашем IE.

Comment: Посмотрел на другом компьютере, вроде действительно там работает. Похоже действительно мой IE просто глючит. Спасибо.